# C++: Designing the interface of a class containing many containers

Tags: c++, class, containers, naming

I couldn't find anything relevant, but sorry if this has been asked already. I sometimes find myself in a sitution in which I have a class, that contains internally say two different containers. Something like the following:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    typedef std::vector<int> int_list;
    typedef std::vector<X> x_list;

    // It would be nice if the user could iterate through these etc. so that I
    // could define functions that operate on them as non-member non-friends.

    typedef int_list::size_type int_list_size_type;
    typedef int_list::const_iterator int_list_const_iter;

    typedef x_list::size_type x_list_size_type;
    typedef x_list::const_iterator x_list_const_iter;

    int_list_const_iter int_list begin() const { return ints_.begin(); }
    x_list_const_iter begin() const { return xs_.begin(); }

    int_list::size_type size_of_ints() const { return ints_.size(); }
    x_list::size_type size_of_xs() const { return xs_.size(); }

    // And so forth ... !

  private:
    int_list ints_;
    x_list xs_;
};
```

Somehow I feel uneasy. Is this is a smart way of doing what I'm doing? Basically, for every container I would need typedefs and (const overloaded) begin and end methods etc. I'm curious: what would be your way of designing the interface, naming the typedefs etc? I guess I'm basically worried about the interface and the explosion of methods, and it looks kinda ugly too.

Maybe one way of limiting the number of begin/end methods would be a template-based approach using somekind of tags, but I'm not sure if that's sensible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your class is doing too much. If your clients need to do all those kinds of operations on those containers, it's probably best if you just expose a constant reference to the container itself instead of trying to wrap every STL interface yourself.

On the other hand, if your clients need to do all those things it's probably a sign that the class needs to be broken apart into smaller classes.

Comment: Quite the opposite, I'd say.  The class isn't doing ENOUGH, if all the operations on the internals happen via. client code.

Comment: +1 to both the answer and the comment: this looks like an awkward middle ground between allowing clients to do whatever they want and ensuring some sort of consistent state between the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried this?  You code won't compile.  You can't have two functions with the same name/param list that return different things.

As to the intent...your misgivings are appropriate and your class is probably not doing enough of its own work to warrant its existence.  The very fact that you want to expose the complete internals of the object so clients can work on them make me conclude that your class is almost certainly 100% useless.  It's a design issue and your misgivings are simply your nose telling you something stinks.

Comment: Well the methods could be renamed, but anyway. Where does one draw a line then? The reason for the begin/end methods was that it's always a bit tricky to predict the future and to me it would seem like a good way to give the client the possibility to do whatever he/she wants.

Comment: "...a good way to give the client the possibility to do whatever he/she wants." <- sort of misses the point of OO--specifically encapsulation--I'm afraid.

Comment: the client can always do whatever he wants. The point in writing a library is to allow the client to do *one specific task* without having to code it himself. If you're not willing to make decisions on behalf of the client, then your library is useless. Every library is an abstraction, a simplification, a specific way to solve a problem. If the client needs it solved in a different way then they'll have to find a different library. You can't do everything. You'll end up doing nothing well.

Answer (score 0):

You should not allow access to the containers. You should export the functionality of the class, and the class should have a central point. Assuming the class is using the containers, e.g. int is a key that references X, you will probably need an interface that coordinates access. In this case you should not provide access to the underlying containers.